# I need help with a simple IR circuit to control electromagnets

Tags: light-sensor

I have a project , I know what I want it to do but don’t know how or the components needed.

I want [this IR beam-break trigger](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2167) to control two of [these 12v magnets](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5Kg-11Lb-4mm-Thread-Dia-Lifting-Magnet-Electromagnet-Solenoid-DC12V-/271567668690?hash=item3f3ab1c5d2:g:QiEAAOSwu4BViuBR) (.33A each). When the beam is broken, I want the magnets to release. As soon as the beam is restored I want the magnets to re-energize.

The 12V power supply is a battery commonly used on lawnmowers. The IR emitter and receiver are 5.5V and 20mA. The distance between 
IR Emitter and Receiver is 6”.

I know this is a simple circuit for most of you but I need help. I don’t know how to make the 5V IR break beam control the 12V relay. Your help would be appreciated. This old man needs help.

Comment: Milli amps are "mA" and not "M". "MA" is reserved for mega amps. Don't quibble in case you are thinking of doing so because accuracy in all areas is required in engineering.

Comment: Question updated with links to OP's specified parts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a diagram of a basic circuit that came to mind while reading your question. Ideally, this may fulfil your need, but otherwise it at least gives us somewhere to start from.
[image: New IR Trigger]

- In this circuit, D1 is your IR LED & "sensor" is your detector.
- The 10Kohm resistor is required by your detector.
- Q1 is a [IRLML6344TRPBF][2] MOSFET ($0.36 @ digikey.com). It "turns on" completely at ~4.5V signal level (so your 5V detector circuit can run it), and can handle ~10x your rated load from your solenoids & 2.5x the voltage; so no relay needed.
- The diode parallel to Q1 "freewheels" to keep coil inductance from causing overvoltage & destruction to Q1 (Q1 has an internal diode to do this to, but better safe...).

Comment: Here are the parts I have ordered. IR Break Beam Sensor

https://www.adafruit.com/products/2167


Electromagnet Solenoid Specifications:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/5Kg-11Lb-4mm-Thread-Dia-Lifting-Magnet-Electromagnet-Solenoid-DC12V-/271567668690?hash=item3f3ab1c5d2:g:QiEAAOSwu4BViuBR

Model
XRN-XP25x20
Rated Voltage
DC 12V
Rated Current
0.33A
Lifting Force
5Kg/ 11Lb
Overall Size
25 x 20mm / 1" x 0.8"(Dia.*T)
Thread Hole Dia
4mm
Lead Length
23cm/ 9.1"
Materials
Metal, Electronic Parts
Weight
53g
Package Content
1 x Electromagnet Solenoid

Comment: Robherc KV5ROB
here are the components I have ordered, I haven’t ordered the relay. Advice on the relay would be appreciated.
 


IR Break Beam Sensor

https://www.adafruit.com/products/2167


Electromagnet 

http://www.ebay.com/itm/5Kg-11Lb-4mm-Thread-Dia-Lifting-Magnet-Electromagnet-Solenoid-DC12V-/271567668690?hash=item3f3ab1c5d2:g:QiEAAOSwu4BViuBR

Comment: Answer updated with new circuit, based on your specified parts.

Comment: Robherc KV5ROB I appreciate the quick response and the circuit design. this will work well for my project.